# Ring and elements with multiplicative decompositions with same sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, model-theory

Is there any commutative unitary ring $(R,+,\cdot,0,1)$, that is *not* an integral domain, with an element $x\neq 1,0$ that presents at least two distinct multiplicative "proper" decompositions (i.e. two couples $\{a,b\}\neq\{c,d\}$ such that $ab=x=cd$ and $a,b,c,d\neq 1$) for which the set $\{a+b\mid ab=x\land a,b\neq 1\}$ is a singleton? I'm looking for an example, but a proof of existence (or not existence) is enough.

Comment: Are you excluding any trivialities due to units?  Like $a1=(-a)(-1)=a$ always gives you $a+1$ and $-a-1$, which you can arrange to be distinct in some rings.  Oh, I just now saw a clause about none of them being $1$. But what about other units?

Comment: See, if you allow units and you have $ab=x$, then you have $(au)(u^{-1}b)=x$, and you probably get a new pair.

Comment: Yes, we could accept units that are not $1$ but, as showed in your example, it could make things worse because gived $ab=x$, the other couple $\{au,u^{-1}b\}$ - that always gives $x$ as product - may probably presents a different sum $au+u^{-1}b\neq a+b$.

Comment: If you wish to exclude it, you'd better do it now before anyone writes an answer based on accepting it.

Comment: if someone finds such a ring satisfying the requests using units it would be great! what I meant is simply that I think it's even more difficult to do it if, in the ring, there are units other than $1$, but... one is free to try it anyway!